# MySQL - Ordering 'featured' items first

Tags: mysql, order-by

I need to have the results of a query show featured items first for a given date before listing the day's other items. You can ignore the categories that are being pulled from another table.

Currently the results list all of the events by date. There is a column in the `eventlisting` table that is called `featured` and has values `1` (featured) or `0` (non-featured). I want the exact same results except that all featured items for that day will list before the non-featured items, for each day. Thank you for any suggestions.

```
SELECT a.*, c.id as catid, c.cat_name FROM eventlisting a 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON a.cat_num=c.id 
WHERE a.startDate >= "2015-08-21" 
AND a.endDate <= "2016-08-21" 
AND a.status=1 
GROUP BY a.id 
ORDER BY a.endDate 
ASC LIMIT 0, 50
```

If this is my table data:

```
id featured status  startDate    endDate
_________________________________________
1      0      1    2015-08-21  2015-08-21
2      0      1    2015-08-21  2015-08-22
3      1      1    2015-08-21  2015-08-25
4      0      0    2015-08-21  2015-08-23
5      1      1    2015-08-22  2015-08-27
6      0      1    2015-08-22  2015-08-31
7      1      1    2015-08-22  2015-08-31
```

Then I need the results to show this order:

```
id featured status  startDate    endDate
_________________________________________
3      1      1    2015-08-21  2015-08-25
1      0      1    2015-08-21  2015-08-21
2      0      1    2015-08-21  2015-08-22
4      0      0    2015-08-21  2015-08-23
5      1      1    2015-08-22  2015-08-27
7      1      1    2015-08-22  2015-08-31
6      0      1    2015-08-22  2015-08-31
```

Comment: I've edited your question in an attempt to remove (or at least reduce) any ambiguity. Please take a look, and feel free to edit further or roll back my changes as necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is `ORDER BY startDate ASC` first, then `featured DESC`:

```
SELECT 
    a.* --,
    -- c.id as catid, 
    -- c.cat_name 
FROM eventlisting a 
-- LEFT JOIN categories c ON a.cat_num=c.id 
WHERE a.startDate >= '2015-08-21'
AND a.endDate <= '2016-08-21' 
AND a.status=1 
GROUP BY a.id 
ORDER BY a.startDate ASC,
         a.featured DESC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

*Note: I've commented the `categories` table because you didn't specified which is its structure.*

**Test:**

```
mysql> SELECT  a.*            FROM eventlisting a   WHERE a.startDate >= '2015-08-21' AND a.endDate <= '2016-08-21'  AND a.status=1  GROUP BY a.id  ORDER BY a.startDate ASC,  a.featured DESC LIMIT 0, 50;
+----+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | featured | status | startDate  | endDate    |
+----+----------+--------+------------+------------+
|  3 |        1 |      1 | 2015-08-21 | 2015-08-25 |
|  1 |        0 |      1 | 2015-08-21 | 2015-08-21 |
|  2 |        0 |      1 | 2015-08-21 | 2015-08-22 |
|  5 |        1 |      1 | 2015-08-22 | 2015-08-27 |
|  7 |        1 |      1 | 2015-08-22 | 2015-08-31 |
|  6 |        0 |      1 | 2015-08-22 | 2015-08-31 |
+----+----------+--------+------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Test it in this **[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b57f5/1)**.